# Manually generated MachineKey is not preserved between deployments

Tags: iis, asp.net-mvc-4, octopus-deploy

I have 2 web servers (Windows 2012) and a single website (ASP.NET MVC 4) on each of them. To make sure ASP.NET encryption works correctly I did the following:

- Deployed the app to both servers using Octopus
- Went to the first server, selected the website, clicked on the Machine Key icon, unchecked all checkboxes, clicked Generate Keys and then clicked Apply
- Then I copied the generated keys to the other machine

This worked but only until the next deployment. The deployment seems to reset the machine key values back to their default values. The deployment process is very simple:

- Stop the app pool
- Delete the content of the app folder
- Copy new files to the app folder
- Start the app pool

As a workaround I have the keys in the web.config but this is far from being perfect for obvious reasons.

Any ideas why the values are being reset?

Thanks

Pawel

Answer (score 1):

Where is IIS putting the machine keys? Into the web.config or into the machine.config?

Also try setting the Octopus variable OctopusNotAWebSite to true and do the IIS re-pointing manually. Octopus could be resetting the IIS Application somehow.

Answer (score 1):

@JasonStangroome solved it for me. I simply forgot that the IIS manager modifies the web.config so that's why custom values would disappear after each deployment.